# HTTP web request doesn't maintain session

Tags: c#, session, webrequest

I have a program where I want to scrap some useful study material for personal use.
This site maintain a session key and some other key also.
If I tried to go to a nested page then it will end the session.

I'm unable to maintain session key using a web request class.

How can I maintain a session using a web request class?

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to maintain the CookiesCollection across your requests.

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/");
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

//Pass the collection along with each request to maintain session
request.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

When you get the response back, your container will automatically contain the set of cookies associated with it. You can then reuse that container with subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you will want to read the session cookie from the response header and pass it back in the header with every request you issue. There may be more to it depending on the application you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar problem when embedding a Page in an iFrame.  Solution is, for security purposes sessions get discarded by browsers (mainly IE8). Maybe this is a splution? Google for P3P to get more info.

-sa