# Session state lost after HttpWebRequest within AJAX post

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, jquery, httpwebrequest

I have a bit of strange behaviour in an `asp.net` web application that involves the session state being lost.

**Process**

A user logs into the application and the session is set. They then fill out 1 field, and the application then does an `AJAX POST` to a `.asmx` web service. Within the web service, I am using a `HttpWebRequest` to grab data from another server.

This data is then output to the browser.

A few more fields are then filled in, and the data is then again `Post` to the same web service via an `AJAX POST`.

**Problem**

Straight after the `HttpWebRequest`, I grab the username from a session variable. This works.
On the next `AJAX` request however, the session no longer exists.

While testing this, I removed the stage at which the `HttpWebRequest` is called and my session is never lost. So for some reason, the session is removed AFTER my first `AJAX POST` and before the second `AJAX POST` only if I am running the `HttpWebRequest` code.

**Code**

I am not doing anything fancy in the code. Just doing a simple jQuery AJAX Post

$.ajax({ 
        url: method, 
        data: params, 
        type: "POST", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { 
                                    // handle data 
                                 },
        error: function(xhr,status,error) { }
   });

Creating a `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` and then getting the `System.Net.HttpWebResponse` out of that.

Then reading a session variable `dim username as string = Session(_SESSION_USERNAME).ToString()`

I have never noticed this behaviour before when using `HttpWebRequest` before (not using any AJAX though)

```
Function Backfill(value As String) As Details

    Dim details As Details = Nothing
    Dim appSettings As ConfigSettings.AppConfig = ConfigSettings.AppConfig.getConfig()

    Dim url As String = appSettings.Settings.BackfillUrl
    Dim username As String = appSettings.Settings.BackfillUser
    Dim password As String = appSettings.Settings.BackfillPass

    Dim expParameters As String = ""
    Dim xml As XmlDocument = Nothing
    Dim xmlHttp As XMLHTTP = Nothing
    Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = Nothing
    Dim node As XmlNode = Nothing
    Dim response As String = ""
    Dim success As String = ""

    '
    ' REMOVED TO HIDE INFO
    expParameters = "<PARAMETERS>" & _            
        "</PARAMETERS>"

    Try

        xmlHttp = New XMLHTTP()
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url)
        xmlHttp.Send(expParameters)

        response = xmlHttp.responseText()

        xml = New XmlDocument
        xml.LoadXml(response)
        SaveExperianFile(xml, value)
        nodeList = xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes
        node = nodeList.Item(0)
        success = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("success").Value.ToString.Trim
        If success.ToLower.Trim = "y" Then
            details = SetDetails(xml)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        If Not xmlHttp Is Nothing Then
            xmlHttp.Dispose()
            xmlHttp = Nothing
        End If
    End Try

    Return details

End Function
```

**edit**

The XMLHTTP Class code can be seen here http://codepaste.net/ymnqsf

**edit**

Seems as though something strange is happening when I am saving the `XMLDocument` to my file system.

```
Private Sub SaveExperianFile(xml As XmlDocument, value As String)
    Dim appConfig As ConfigSettings.AppConfig = ConfigSettings.AppConfig.getConfig()
    Try
        xml.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(appConfig.Settings.SavePath & value & "_backfill.xml"))
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

If I don't call this method, then the session is always set.

**Question**

Do you know what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Something is resetting the session. Could it be possible for you to post the webservice code?

Comment: updated with code for the `HttpWebRequest` the webservice isnt doing anything fancy apart from calling the `HttpWebRequest` code, reading the session, and saving to a `SQL` database

Comment: Can you check to see if the session.sessionid is the same on the second request?

Comment: It is straight forward code. I guess SaveExperianFile is making DB call. At which place you are setting the session?

Comment: @ARS the SaveExperianFile is just saving the XML document to the file system. It is after I have called `Backfill` that I am then checking for the session.

Comment: Can you check if you just loose the session or the whole application is restarted. If you are saving the XML in the virtual directory / web application folder then it might case web application to restart. If many dozen files were added in short succession to each other, that would be a case to restart the App Pool.

Comment: WOW. That is it. When calling `xml.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(appConfig.Settings.SavePath & value & "_backfill.xml"))` It is doing something that is causing the session to be lost. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I am happy to know that my response did help you. As suggested, I have posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check if you just loose the session or the whole application is restarted. If you are saving the XML in the virtual directory / web application folder then it might case web application to restart. If many dozen files were added in short succession to each other, that would be a case to restart the App Pool.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was convinced it was something to do with the `HttpWebRequest` and didn't even think about the code which was saving the `XmlDocument`. Still no closer to finding out WHY it is doing this though, but I have removed that part of the code and it has stopped my session issues.

Comment: Turned out the files were being saved within a folder that was in the `bin` directory. Schoolboy error :P

Comment: Aha now it make sense why the application was restarting :)

Comment: Not only add files on the bin directory can cause this problem! I have an application that saved files on WebApplication\tmp directory and that caused Session loss. Moving the directory outside the Application root directory, finally solved the problem. Thanks ARS! :-)

Answer (score 0):

just a hunch, but maybe you need to maintain cookies across HttpWebRequests.

have a look at this question for more help.

[Http web request doesn't maintaining session](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2457771/168371)

Comment: I will give it a go. Not sure though why the session is still set after the `HttpWebRequest` but then not on the 2nd `AJAX POST`

Comment: Sorry this did not help. Thanks though for the answer.